# HttpGetAttribute name property not working for routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have a WebAPI controller named *WeatherForecast* with one operation. The operation method looks like follow:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

However, the `HttpGet.Name = "GetWeatherForecast"` should define a route name "GetWeatherForecast" as I understand the purpose of the `Name` property for this attribute.

But Swagger shows me that the operation itself has no route at all:
The displayed URL is **https://localhost:port/WeatherForecast**
(the service operation can be consumed through that URL, I used Postman for testing)

But with the `HttpGet` attribute with the `Name` property set, I would expect it to be  https://localhost:port/WeaterhForecast/**GetWeatherForecast**

When I additionally use the `Route` attribute (`Route("GetWeatherForecast")`) on the operation method, then the route for the operation is shown as follows: https://localhost:port/WeaterhForecast/**GetWeatherForecast**
(the service operation is indeed now accessible through that URL).

So, the question is: Why is the `Name` property of `HttpGet` attribute not doing what documentation promised? Or what is `HttpGetAttribute.Name` really for?

The source code was made with .NET 6.0 with VS 2022, project type ASP.NET Core-Web-API. The shown code is from the automatically created controller by project template.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way you have used the `HttpGet` attribute:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
```

Means you are specifying the [`Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.httpmethodattribute.name?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-routing-httpmethodattribute-name) property which doesn't change how the URL for the route is generated. The route name can be used to generate a link using a specific route, instead of relying on the selection of a route based on the given set of route values.

Instead, you should specify the [`Template`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.routing.httpmethodattribute.template?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-routing-httpmethodattribute-template) property, either by excluding the named parameter or using the correct name:

```
[HttpGet("GetWeatherForecast")]
```

Or:

```
[HttpGet(Template = "GetWeatherForecast")]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification! Seems I mixed up the two properties and overlooked the default constructor of HttpGet

Comment: **"The route name can be used to generate a link using a specific route, instead of relying on the selection of a route based on the given set of route values."** Would be good if you could add an example code.

Answer (score 0):

@DavidG is right, using `[HttpGet("GetWeatherForecast")]` instead of `[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]` works for me. I was stuck on the same issue for many days, tried a lot of workarounds and followed almost all of the suggestions available on the internet in different forums but the solution which worked like a charm was to remove the `Name` attribute inside your controller.

This is indeed a strange fact that using `[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]` does work as it implies it will do and if you use something like:

```
routes.MapGet("/api/Pnrlog/{id}", (int id) =>
        {
            return new Pnrlog { PnrlogId = id };
        })
        .WithName("GetPnrlogById");
```

it also does not work like that....

Answer (score 0):

This **does not answer the question**, but adds an interesting bit, which must surely add to clarify the difference between `Name` and `Template` goals (although I am unable to formally tell what it is):

**Assuming you are using the Visual Studio Web Api project template** - removing the `Name` property to use template instead, allows finally to access the resource by specifying the full route: `https://localhost:7008/WeatherForecast/GetWeatherForecast`.
But - accessing that same resource by specifying the route up to the controller alone - does not return results anymore.

**In a short:**

1. With the `Name` property, the `Get` method (named `GetWeatherForecast`), the resource can be accessed with routing up to the controller alone: `https://localhost:7008/WeatherForecast`. Trying to access the resource by its full route, fails (404).
2. With the Template property instead, resource can be accessed by using full route: `https://localhost:7008/WeatherForecast/GetWeatherForecast`. Trying to access it routing to the controller alone, fails (404).

---

```
[HttpGet("GetWeatherForecast")]
//[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
```