# Adding new method to controller makes swagger give 500 error

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, controller

It's been a while since I made an API. Now I was looking at it again and I tried to simply add a get method to the `WeatherForecastController`. But I keep getting a swagger error after adding it. The method looks very similar to the existing method. only that this one uses a parameter. But after adding it I keep getting an error in my browser. and I'm not sure why. I haven't done this in a very long time. And I never used swagger before.

[image: Screenshot]

Note that I simply created the project and added the method that is all I did. This is the browser error.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Maybe, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70877094/3986304), the missing information here is: you should not use the placeholder `Name`. Remove the placeholder and use the constructor with the string only or use the `Template` placeholder. Take care about the parameter `amount`, though. If you don't insert it inside the template, you'll only be able to pass it through QueryString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for future reference.

Step 1:-> Open your dev tools, or just F12.

```
      Then open the network tab, and refresh your page.
```

[image]

Step 2:> Click on the swagger call and click on the response tab.

You will see your error:

*Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Conflicting method/path combination "GET WeatherForecast" for actions - WebApplication1.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.Get (WebApplication1),WebApplication1.Controllers.WeatherForecastController.GetAmount (WebApplication1). Actions require a unique method/path combination for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0. Use ConflictingActionsResolver as a workaround*

[image]

Try routing like this

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Change `[Route("[controller]")]` to
`[Route("[controller]/[action]")]`

Answer (score 3):

Try this;

```
[HttpGet("GetWeatherForecast")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}

[HttpGet("GetNumberOfForecasts/{amount}")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> GetAmount(int amount)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(1, amount).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by adding route as below.

[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
[! [Redefine the route with respect to action.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAtj5.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAtj5.png)